# css - Unexpected display of ckeditor content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using `Ckeditor` in my `React` project
When I enter the text and use `numbered List` in the input box, there are 2 unexpected problems below:

1. the input box not showing the number
2. The numbers are outside the Result box

How to solve it?

[image]

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/async-currying-k77fu?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the numbers in the editor are out of box because of your `*{padding:0}`, it also puts the numbers out of your div below.
You might remove it, or add padding to `ol` element to fix this.